# Reverse loop for date display

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure this out and can't seem to get it.

Here is the code..

```
   $m= date("m");
   $de= date("d");
   $y= date("Y");
   for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
       echo "<br>";
       echo date('m/d',mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de+$i),$y));
       echo "<br>";
   }
```

It displays the following.

```
04/08

04/07

04/06

04/05

04/04

04/03

04/02
```

That is exactly what I want, but I want it to flip around so echos it would look like the following.

```
04/02

04/03

04/04

04/05

04/06

04/07

04/07
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this one's easier, isn't it:

```
for($i=-6; $i<=0; $i++){
   printf('<br>%s<br>', date('m/d', strtotime("+$i days")));
}
```

prints

```
<br>04/02<br><br>04/03<br><br>04/04<br><br>04/05<br><br>04/06<br><br>04/07<br><br>04/08<br>
```

Answer (score 5):

How about changing the order:

```
for($i=6; $i>=0; $i--)
```